# Add CORS to UseFileServer in OWIN

Tags: c#, .net, cors, owin, katana

I've been trying to get the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header added to files served using a self-hosted Owin Application

Here's my startup class so far

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"C:\test"),
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
        });
    }
}
```

I found the UseCors function, but it doesn't seem to help.

i've also looked around and tried to override the UseFileServer method, and manually modify the headers, but had no such luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are doing the same thing as I am but, adding this to the App.Config file helped

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```